# How to Drag row from NSOutlineView to NSTableview

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4.2, nsdragginginfo

I am learning drag and drop in cocoa...
  I am unable to drag row from `NSOutlineView`  to drop in `NSTableView` its to difficult for me..
  I have tried the following methods..

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView writeItems:(NSArray *)items toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard proposedChildIndex:(NSInteger)index
- (NSDragOperation)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView validateDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedItem:(id)item proposedChildIndex:(NSInteger)index
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info item:(id)item childIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

but i can't perform darg and drop.

Comment: Which version of xcode you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also have to call `registerForDraggedTypes:` on the destination table view in order to register which drop types the tableview will accept.

Comment: Drag and Drop is working perfectly. Now I need to delete the draged row in `NSOutlineView` please guide me to solve this problem...

Comment: Remove the row from your NSTreeController or other data source you are using to drive the NSOutlineView. The outline will automatically update if you use binding or you'll have to do a -reloadData.

Comment: I am using 'NSMutableArray' to the  'NSOutlineView' data source. How can i find the dragged row... And how to delete... sorry I am new to cocoa..

Comment: You can temporary store the items in `outlineView:writeItems:toPasteboard:` and after the drag is completed you can delete the items from the array.

Comment: I need to delete row when the drop operation accepted. I have use two class for  `NSOutlineView`  and `NSTableView` delegate. When I delete the dragged row from `NSOutlineView` in `NSTableView` class it not delete the row. the outlineview is not update.